# Sails.js lifecycle callbacks for removeFromCollection / addToCollection

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I want to get some kind of callback when adding / removing entities from a model's collection to validate the added entity. The official documentation only states that `create`, `update` and `destroy` are supported.

I was hoping that `update` would also trigger when using `removeFromCollection` or `addToCollection`, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Is there any other convenient way that allows me to check for collection updates?

Comment: Have you checked sails lifecycle callbacks? I suppose that could be helpful for you. https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks
You can use methods like `afterUpdate()` which will be triggered after update of collection.

Comment: @khushalbokadey That is exactly what I've done and as I've said in my question, the update lifecycle hooks did NOT trigger when adding or removing from a collection.